# Possible to get an ElasticSerach template to pick up existing indexes?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an ElasticSearch template that includes several indices and creates several aliases.  When testing I've always created my template (and the underlying aliases) first and then the indexes.  When I do this the aliases show up as expected.  I'm not in a situation where the indexes already exist on a test environment and when I created my template there the aliases are not showing up.

Am I correct in assuming that the reason the aliases aren't showing is because the indexes already existed?  If that is correct, is there a way to get the template to pick up the indices without deleting and re-creating the indices?  Why is it that the indices need to be created after the template in order to be picked up?

I'm new to ElasticSerach so if the answer is obvious here I apologize.  I looked through the documentation for templates, indexes and aliases but couldn't find an explanation for the behavior I was seeing.

Answer (score 1):

Templates are only applied in the index creation.

If you create an index before you created the template that would match that index, this template won't be applied, the same things happens if you change something in your template like the number of shards or aliases.

From the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-templates.html#index-templates) about index templates you have:

> An index template is a way to tell Elasticsearch how to configure an index when it is created.

And

> Templates are configured **prior to index creation**. When an index is created - either manually or through indexing a document - the template settings are used as a basis for creating the index.

If you define your alias in the template it will only be applied to index created after the creation of the template, if you want to set alias to existing indices you will need to do it manually using the [alias API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-aliases.html#indices-aliases).

You can't apply templates to existing indices.